# FormArray return null?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, formarray

Greeting. I've tried multiple ways, but none of them work. I'm on this, right now. I need to initiate a formArray of emails

```
email: [testestest]
```

But I got:

```
email: [testestest]
```

But my email return  n click. Check my ts

And my html:

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex, you has an Form Array of FormControls, not an Form Array of formGroups. So you .html must be like

```
<form *ngIf="addForm" [formGroup]="addForm">
    <div class="form-control-row" formArrayName="email"
        *ngFor="let item of addForm.get('email').controls; let i = index;">
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="E - mail" [formControlName]="i">
            <img src="../../assets/Delete.svg" alt="x-icon">
      </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

See that you has no [fomGroupName]="i", and you use [formControlName]="i"

Other way is

```
<form *ngIf="addForm" [formGroup]="addForm">
    <div class="form-control-row" formArrayName="email"
        *ngFor="let item of addForm.get('email').controls; let i = index;">
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="E - mail" [formControl]="item">
            <img src="../../assets/Delete.svg" alt="x-icon">
      </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

See that in this case we use [formControl]="item" (item is the variable you use in the 
*ngFor)

Well, how you create the formArray?

If you has an array of emails you can do

```
    email:  this.formBuilder.array(
             this.email.map(x=>this.formBuilder.control(x))
          )
```

That's you create an array of FormControls using map (transform each element of the array in a FormControl who value the element of the array.

NOTE: In production you need create a getter for the array

```
get emails()
{
    return this.form.get('email') as FormArray;
}
```

And iterate over

```
    *ngFor="let item of emails.controls; let i = index;">
```

The use of [formGroupName]="i" and formControl it's used with a FormArray of FormGroups. e.g. you can has

```
    email:  this.formBuilder.array(
             this.email.map(x=>this.formBuilder.group({email:x}))
          )
```

See that in this case transform each element of the array in a formGroup that has a FormControl "called" email

You can see all this in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t99cea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). I hope the example help you understand the diference

If we want to add an element to the formArray we can make a function

```
  addEmail(email:any)
  {
    const array=this.addForm.get('email') as FormArray 
    array.push(this.formBuilder.control(email)) //if is a FormArray of FormControl

    const array2=this.addForm.get('email2') as FormArray
    array2.push(this.formBuilder.group({email:email})) //if is a FormArray of FormGroup
  }
```

NOTE: At first, if we want to create a empty formArray we need use

```
    email:  this.formBuilder.array([])
```

When we want delete an element of the array, we need pass the "index" of the array, so our function delete is

```
delete(index:number)
  {
    const array=this.addForm.get('email') as FormArray
    array.removeAt(index)

  }
```

and our .html is

```
  <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="E - mail" [formControl]="item">
        <img src="../../assets/Delete.svg" alt="x-icon" (click)="delete(i)">
  </div>
```

Comment: When i set email:  this.formBuilder.array(
             this.email.map(x=>this.formBuilder.group({email:x}))
          ) in onInit form i got error  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'FormArray'.ts(2339)

Comment: How to iterate without already created Array email: [....] ?
@eliseo

Comment: @alexic93939, I update the answer (and the stackblitz) to create a function to Add an emal. About the error, I don't know where you put the code. take account that, when you create the formArray you need create as array -it's can be empty, but need to be an arrat-

Comment: I have dynamic field and I can add 3or 4 new fields..?

Comment: You save my day! @Elise Thank you!
Can you please just help me to add remove single fields? Thank you!

Comment: again updated the answer and the stackblitz. Is just in the (click) pass the "index" `(click)="delete(i)"` and use removeAt in the function

Comment: This is unreal!! Thank you bro!!!
I have only one question more..only one.
How to display one input field already set up? Just one fileld set up , other fileds dynamic add? 
Thank you again! Vote UP!

Comment: you can call to this.addEmail(null) in code so many times you need or, when you has create the array use set value to give value to a field. You only remember that to "reach" the element in a FormArray you need use "at", e.g. `(this.addForm.get('email') as FormArray).at(2).setValue({email:'new email')` -change the value of the 3re element of the array -rmemebr the arrays begins with 0), take a look to the docs https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: Hmm this formArray is new for me.. I am not sure to know how do it :(

Comment: I update the stackblitz with some differents ways to create and change a form array, I hope this can help you

Comment: In stackblitz you are change much code. This is much different